# Database query with 'and' 'or' and negate condition

Tags: database, powershell

I am trying to understand why this is working as expected and the later dosn't.

> a1 or a2 or a3 ---> works

I want to get all the other parts that are not in the first expression.

> match'a*' and (not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3') ---> doesn't work

Same one as the previous works as expected if all the conditions used are '**and**', **Why is that?** I was sure my logic is good.

Is it possible when negating expression conditions also should be negated? Even if so, if I do

> match'a*' and not'a1' ---> works

It works fine for one object but not more than one.

Comment: `NOT (a1 OR a2)` is not same as `(NOT a1 OR NOT a2)`, it's `(NOT a1 AND NOT a2)`

Comment: I think you got me right.

Comment: It looks like the system we are working on (Nexthink Finder), can not do grouping when negating.

Comment: So even if my logic was good with this: `(NOT a1 OR NOT a2)`

Comment: Your statement to convert this `(NOT a1 OR NOT a2)` into this `(NOT a1 AND NOT a2)` was perfect.

Comment: Make sense? If yes, I really would like to understand that better.

Comment: I will put it in an answer below

Comment: Thank you sir! I was trying to use these two web sites to understand and visualize it better: https://www.dcode.fr/  and https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: I use `wolframalpha` a lot, but this is more a theoretical question, related to the set theory. I put a link to wikipedia article which will be a good starting pint to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'a1' -match 'a.*' -and (
    'a1' -notlike 'a1' -or # false - move on to next evaluation
    'a1' -notlike 'a2' -or # true - found true, so whole evaluation is true
    'a1' -notlike 'a3'
)

'a1' -match 'a.*' -and (
    'a1' -notlike 'a1' -and # false - stop evaluating and return false since all must be true to return true
    'a1' -notlike 'a2' -and 
    'a1' -notlike 'a3'
)
```

Comment: In my case the first expression didn't work, but the second did work.
That's what I don't understand. I expected the first one to work.

Answer (score 0):

The technical reason why `not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3'` fails comes in two parts.

One, the overall condition is

```
match'a*' and (Result of the comparisons.)
```

Two, the comparisons evaluated to True.

Use `a1` as input.

1. a1 not'a1' = False
2. a1 not'a2' = True
3. a1 not'a3' = True

Remember that operators only work on two values at a time. In PowerShell, operators evaluate from left to right. And the result from one comparison is used as the left-hand side of later comparisons.

Logical OR is True when either statement is True.

1. a1 not'a1' [False] or a1 not'a2' [True] = True
2. (a1 not'a1' or a1 not'a2' [True]) or a1 not'a3' [True] = True

---

If `a1` is your input then `match'a*'` evaluates to True and your comparisons evaluate to True.

```
True and (True)
```

So `a1` is accepted for

```
match'a*' and (not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3')
```

---

The reason why `not'a1' and not'a2' and not'a3'` succeeds is:

Logical AND is True when both statements are True.

1. a1 not'a1' [False] and a1 not'a2' [True] = False
2. (a1 not'a1' and a1 not'a2' [False]) and a1 not'a3' [True] = False

If `a1` is your input then `match'a*'` evaluates to True and your comparisons evaluate to False.

```
True and (False)
```

So `a1` is rejected for

```
match'a*' and (not'a1' and not'a2' and not'a3')
```

You need to practice manually evaluating conditions.

References

- [about_Logical_Operators - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.1)

## Update 01

With respect to

```
match'a*' and (not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3')
```

it is correct to say that

> which will basically include everything because it's likely that any value will evaluate to True in at least 2 of those evaluations.

because **any value** will be `not'a1'` or `not'a2'`.

---

```
match'a*' and (not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3')
```

For example, if I input `a1` then `not'a1'` is False. `not'a2'` is True.

```
match'a*' and (False or True or not'a3')
```

So the program will evaluate `False OR True`.

Logical OR is True when either statement is True.

So `False OR True` is evaluated to True.

```
match'a*' and (True or not'a3')
```

`not'a3'` is True.

```
match'a*' and (True or True)
```

So the program will evaluate `True OR True`.

`True OR True` is evaluated to True.

```
match'a*' and (True)
```

`match'a*'` is True.

```
True and (True)
```

So the program will evaluate `True AND True`.

Logical AND is True when both statements are True.

So `True AND True` is evaluated to True.

```
True
```

The final result when using `a1` as input is True.

---

```
match'a*' and (not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3')
```

If I input `a2` then `not'a1'` is True. `not'a2'` is False.

```
match'a*' and (True or False or not'a3')
```

So the program will evaluate `True OR False`.

`True OR False` is evaluated to True.

```
match'a*' and (True or not'a3')
```

`not'a3'` is True.

```
match'a*' and (True or True)
```

So the program will evaluate `True OR True`.

`True OR True` is evaluated to True.

```
match'a*' and (True)
```

`match'a*'` is True.

```
True and (True)
```

So the program will evaluate `True AND True`.

`True AND True` is evaluated to True.

```
True
```

The final result when using `a2` as input is True.

---

`a3`

```
match'a*' and (not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3')
match'a*' and (True or True or not'a3')
match'a*' and (True or not'a3')
match'a*' and (True or False)
match'a*' and (True)
True and (True)
True
```

---

`a4`

```
match'a*' and (not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3')
match'a*' and (True or True or not'a3')
match'a*' and (True or not'a3')
match'a*' and (True or True)
match'a*' and (True)
True and (True)
True
```

---

Because that statement uses logical OR comparisons, there is no input that will cause them all to be False. When at least one of the statements is True, that causes the whole clause `(not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3')` to evaluate to True at the end.

Only the first condition can fail the test.

`b1`

```
match'a*' and (not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3')
match'a*' and (True or True or not'a3')
match'a*' and (True or not'a3')
match'a*' and (True or True)
match'a*' and (True)
False and (True)
False
```

---

When you say

> anything that equals 'a1', 'a2', or 'a3'.

or

> anything that is not 'al', 'a2', or 'a3'.

or

> anything that is not equal to 'a1' AND not equal to 'a2' AND not equal to 'a3'.

you are making confusing generalizations of a concrete process.

My advice is to evaluate the statements individually while following precedence as I've done above. That's what the computer will do. It will always give the right answer without guessing.

Comment: This worked:

`match'a*' and (not'a1' and not'a2' and not'a3')`


And this didn't:

`match'a*' and (not'a1' or not'a2' or not'a3')`

Comment: That's exactly why I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You are saying that in the first expression you get anything that equals 'a1', 'a2', or 'a3'.  Then in the next expression you want anything that is not 'al', 'a2', or 'a3'.  this means you want anything that is not equal to 'a1' AND not equal to 'a2' AND not equal to 'a3'.  You don't want any of those values.  if you use OR then you are saying if it's not equal to 'a1' include it OR if its not equal to a2 then include it OR not equal to a3 then include it which will basically include everything because it's likely  that any value will evaluate to true in at least 2 of those evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to think about NOT (a1 OR a2)

First small theory: `NOT`, `AND` and `OR` are logical operators. A logical operator is a symbol or word used to connect two or more expressions. As a mathematical constructs, there are rules associated with them.

By saying `NOT (a1 or a2)` what we mean is that we are searching for the expression that is neither a1 nor it's a2. And here enters the confusion. Pay attention how I constructed the senate with the `nor` and `neither`. As people we are used to this line of thinking which leads us to write `NOT a1 OR NOT a2`. Although our natural logical intention is correct, from the perspective of the mathematics (where this problem belongs), the formal expression is wrong.

Since `a1` and `a2` are sets, we are "looking for an element that do not belong to set `a1` and also at the same time do not belong to the set `a2`". What we are searching that are outside of the union of both sets. And this line of thinking helps to construct the proper expression `NOT a1 AND NOT a2`, or the we are: "looking for an element that is not at the same time member of a1 or member of a2" which means `NOT (a1 or a2)`.

Going back to `NOT a1 OR NOT a2`. For operator `OR` to yield `true` it's enough only one of the operands to yield `true`. So if an element is `NOT a1` the statement will return `true` regardless if the second operant is true or not, so if second operand is member of the set `a2` that do not intersects with `a1`, the statement will return `true`. But this is not what we want. This is why we need to use the operator `AND` which requires both operands to be `true` before he can return `true`

If you want to know more about the formal mathematics related to this issue, this is called DeMorgan's law, and this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) can help you understand how it arrives. It also has good graphical illustrations that help to understand the logic behind it.